# How to get pdf link from NCBI pmc website site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the .pdf link from this web page: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9618240/

I am using requests and BeautifulSoup to get the html content and parse it. I am targeting the outer class `pmc-sidebar__formats` and the inner class `pdf-link` to find the element that contains the pdf link. However, when I print the outer links, I get an empty list.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9618240"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Target the outer class containing links
outer_links = soup.find_all(class_="pmc-sidebar__formats")  # Replace with the actual outer class name
print(outer_links)
for outer_link in outer_links:
    inner_links = outer_link.find_all(class_="pdf-link")  # Replace with the actual inner class name
    for inner_link in inner_links:
        href = inner_link.get("href")
        if href and href.endswith(".pdf"):
            url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov" + href
            print(href)  # Print the PDF link
            #os.system("axel " + url)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the pdf link from this web page? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to directly extract the PDF link from the script tag within the HTML. Often, websites include such information in a script tag, which can be parsed without the need for a headless browser.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9618240"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Extract the script tag content containing information about PDF links
script_tag = soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
if script_tag:
    # Parse the JSON content within the script tag
    script_content = json.loads(script_tag.string)
    
    # Extract the PDF link from the parsed JSON content
    pdf_links = script_content.get("hasPart", [])
    
    # Print the PDF links
    for pdf_link in pdf_links:
        if pdf_link.get("@type") == "MediaObject" and pdf_link.get("fileFormat") == "application/pdf":
            print(pdf_link.get("contentUrl"))
else:
    print("Script tag not found.")
```

This script attempts to locate the script tag with type "application/ld+json" and parse its content as JSON. It then extracts information about PDF links. Keep in mind that the structure of the JSON content may vary from website to website, so adjust the script accordingly based on the actual structure of the JSON content on the specific page you're working with.

Comment: it is taking too much time and i just need only pdf link

Comment: @Aman007, please try updated code now